# PHP: Find out all the keys with the same value in an associative array

Tags: php

Are there any functions in PHP that help find out all the keys with the same value in an associative array? For example, there is an array as follows:

> $data1 = array("Peter" => "1", "Ann" => "1", "Susan" => "2", "Tom"=> "3");

I only want the keys with the value "1" (i.e. Peter and Ann). Thanks for help.

Comment: You must have tried something? Any google attempts to find a solution? Anything?

Comment: you can create your own function by using foreach loop and array_push() to the return value

Answer (score 6):

You can use [`array_keys`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php) with the optional second parameter:

> `array_keys()` returns the keys, numeric and string, from the array.
>
> If the optional `search_value` is specified, then only the keys for that value are returned. Otherwise, all the keys from the array are returned.

Answer (score 2):

Use array_intersect and array_keys.

```
$data1 = array("Peter" => "1", "Ann" => "1", "Susan" => "2", "Tom"=> "3");
$find = 1;
Var_dump(array_keys(array_intersect($data1, [$find])));
```

https://3v4l.org/DICDB

Comment: Thanks for your help, Andreas! A further question: Is there any way that helps find out "1" is the value which several keys in the array have.

Comment: You can use `Echo array_keys(array_count_values($data1))[0];` which will first count all values and list them with value "1" having two entries. Then I use array_keys and echo the first which mean the key that has the most equal values.

Comment: @jiten2015 is that what you wanted?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have tried the code provided. It seems that a number will be generated only based on the value of the first key in the array ($data1[0]). Is there anything I have missed ?

Comment: @jiten2015 sorry that is true.  You need sort the count array descending and then grab the first value. See this example: https://3v4l.org/A06D0 . I set $find as the first value of count array since that is the maximum count

Comment: Thank you for your explanation.